# Using CLT do estimate the probability that $S_{n}\in[a,b]$ for given $n,a,b$

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following question (taken from an old test
in my probability course):

> Let $\{A_{i}\}_{i=1}^{300}$ be I.I.D R.V s.t $A_{1}\sim U([1,3])$.
>
> Define $S_{300}=\sum_{i=1}^{300}A_{i}$. Estimate $P(604\leq
>  S_{300}\leq615.2)$

**What I tried to do:**

I know that if $X\sim U([1,3])$ then $EX=\frac{1+3}{2}=2$.

I have also calculated $EX^{2}=\frac{3^{3}-1^{3}}{3}=\frac{8}{3}$
hence $\sigma^{2}(X)=\frac{8}{3}-2=\frac{2}{3}$.

Using CLT :$$P(S_{300}\leq615.2)=P(\frac{S_{300}-300\cdot2}{\sqrt{300}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}\leq\frac{615.2-300\cdot2}{\sqrt{300}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}})=\approx P(X_{0,1}\leq\frac{1.52}{\sqrt{2}})$$

Where $X_{0,1}\sim N(0,1)$.

Also $$P(S_{300}\geq604)=1-P(S_{300}<604)=1-P(S_{300}\leq604)$$

and this is estimated in a similar fashion.

What I don't know is how to calculate the probability that $S_{300}$
is both $\leq615.2$ and $\geq604$.

I know that generally $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=P(B)P(A|B)$$, but I don't
know how to calculate the probability that $S_{300}\leq615.2$ given
that it is $\geq604$ or vice versa.

Any help with the problem is appreciated

Comment: For a continuous variable $X$, we have $P[a\le X\le b]=P[X\le b]-P[X\le a]$ (just interpret probabilities in terms of areas under the graph of the density).

Comment: Check your variance calculation

Comment: @leonbloy - thanks, I was just about to edit that part after noticing the mistake - but I get that it should be $EX^{2}=\frac{3^{3}-1^{3}}{3}=\frac{26}{3}$
hence $\sigma^{2}(X)=\frac{26}{3}-4=\frac{14}{3}$ and the answer say it is $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @DavidMitra - thanks, you can make it an answer, its a good one

Comment: @leonbloy - I got the mistake, I assumed the density is $1$ by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a continuous variable X, we have $P[a≤X≤b]=P[X≤b]−P[X≤a]$.

One way to see this is to just interpret probabilities in terms of areas under the graph of the density function of $X$.